# Can I see the exact commands IntelliJ uses to build a java project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can I see the exact commands IntelliJ uses to build a java project?

Answer (score 22):

IDEA is not running java binary, so there is no way to see the commands. Instead, IDEA uses Java compiler API directly. If you want a raw representation of what is done to build the project, you can use **Build | Generate Ant** build. Examine the build file or run it from the command line via Ant to see what happens and what options/commands are invoked.

Comment: IJ12 has "external compiler" options.  Is there a better way, now?

Comment: These options are not available when IntelliJ manages compilation directly rather than through Ant.   Is there an easy way to switch between Ant and IntelliJ's native build process?

Answer (score 21):

Look in ~/Library/Logs/IdeaIC13/build-log. You can turn on ALL debugging in build-log.xml in this directory. When you build inside IDEA, it writes a log to build.log in this directory.

Comment: Damn bro, that piece of info about the `build.log` file was so valuable to me! Thanks!

Comment: For linux users check `~/.IntelliJIdeaYYYY.X/system/log/build-log/build.log`, where `YYYY.X` is the intellij version e.g. `2018.1`.

Comment: Version 2020.2 uses `~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea*.*/log/build-log/build.log`

Comment: On macOS, IntelliJ version 2021.1 it's at `/Users/<your user>/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/build-log/build.log`

Comment: On Windows, the logs are at `%AppData%\..\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\log\build-log` (paste that into the explorer path) in the file `build.log`.

Comment: Sadly, these logs did NOT contain what I was looking for.

Comment: Even when I turn off IntelliJ, add the line `org.jetbrains.jps.level=ALL` to `build-log-jul.properties` (on Windows), and restart IntelliJ, I see no useful information in these logs.

Comment: @BrettY In my system the directory is ./.IdeaIC/log/build-log

Answer (score 15):

**For figuring out exact Run command, not exact Build command**:

If you run a certain run configuration, check the output console (Ctrl+0)
For example, it shows something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The first line is the command for running the module...

Comment: If your compilation is successful, the message console will disappear to leave a deliberate compilation error in your code and you will be able then review the build command.

Comment: @Attrill As of Intelij Idea 17, for example it just shows command line to run already built file, not to build it. Ctrl+0 doesn't work for displaying build command line for me, too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the output of a build directly, but you can view and edit the compiler options IntelliJ uses, in the Compiler tab of the Settings dialog.

Answer (score -7):

CTRL-F9

for all key commands you can check ( and print) the keymap, its available in hte help tab.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`F9` builds the project, but it doesn't show the command used for the build