# Intellij debugging Intellij for plugin development

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, plugins

I want to analyze (by looking at logs or debugging) what cli commands (like invoking the jvm with some options, etc) does IntelliJ invoke beneath the hood when i run or debug an project in it. Or, maybe what command it fires on cli if i run a gradle task.

I don't like all the over configuration that IntelliJ provides and want to look beneath the hood for the architecture and workflow of the same. I am interested in developing a plugin for it.

How do i go about it?

I would be more interested if you could provide a better track to follow or give some hints as to where do I start like if you can tell me if there's a config option in IntelliJ to see commands fired by it to the CLI.. I would appreciate if people who have even slight experience with IntelliJ internals or its plugin development can provide some guidance.

TIA

Comment: The command IDE executes when you launch run/debug configuration is printed in the very first line in the console tab of the run/debug tool window.

Comment: so I just clone  intellij community edition repo  and start debugging thereon?

Comment: You don't need to debug anything. Simply run your project and look in the Run or Debug toolwindow, the command is printed there.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966530/can-i-see-the-exact-commands-intellij-uses-to-build-a-java-project